# pushing docker to docker hub with Spotify maven plugin

Tags: maven, spring-boot, docker

I am trying to push a simple springboot docker image to private docker hub repository, but I get the error. I am using **spring-boot-maven-plugin** to do this and I want the image to be pushed when I run **mvn deploy**

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project app: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

How do I have to setup the repository parameters in pom for this to work?

My pom:

```
 <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>

                    <repository>my_username/project_name</repository>
                    <tag>${project.version}</tag>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                            <goal>push</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Comment: I'm not really a java guy, but it looks like somewhere in the POM you should define the URL it should be targeting the deploy to

Comment: yes I agree but I can not find an example, I assumed that the docker hub should be the default anyway for the spotify maven plugin but looks like it is not

Comment: It's probably not so much the application URL, but rather the repo URL. IE in docker, pushing an image as myusername/application:tag assumes that it's targeting dockerhub. It might just be looking for the myusername/application:tag part. I'll dig around a little later and see if I can find anything

Comment: tnx for info, I have double-checked that username/application is the same as on the private docker-hub repo I have, I have actually copy pasted it from docker hub